# How could an estimator be biased but consistent according to mathematical definition?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

According to the definition, an estimator can be biased, if $E_{\theta}[\hat{\theta}]\ne\theta$, with $\theta$ as parameter for a distribution we want to get from samples. While the estimator can be consistent if $\hat{\theta}\overset{p}{\to}\theta$.  How could an estimator be consistent but biased?  In other words, how could it be, that $\hat{\theta}\overset{p}{\to}\theta$ may not lead to $E_{\theta}[\hat{\theta}]\ne\theta$?

Comment: Do you realize that $\hat\theta$ is actually $\hat\theta_n$ depending on the sample size $n$? Does this remark solve your problem?

Comment: $\large{\hat \sigma ^2=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(X_i-\overline X)^2}{n}}$ is a biased estimator but consistent estimator for $\sigma ^2$.

Comment: As pointed out above, an estimator can be biased, but asymptotically unbiased for the parameter $\theta$, i.e. the bias tends to $0$ when the sample size $n$ tends to infinity. Another trivial example: Consider the sample mean $\hat{p}$ for a Bernoulli($p$) sample - $\hat{p}$ is an unbiased estimator for $p$. Now if we consider another estimator $\tilde{p} = \hat{p} + \frac {1} {n}$, then this is biased estimator but it is consistent.